# can a computer work with software interrupts only?

Tags: hardware, interrupt

can software interrupts do some of hardware interrupts?
can it detect power failure and things and then rely only on software interrupts?
so then we wont need special hardware like interrupt controllers

Answer (score 0):

While this may be technically possible I doubt you'll end up with a system that's stable or even reliable. Interrupts are especially important as hardware because they, well, interrupt the processing of other tasks *asynchronously*. This allows physical components at their lowest level to quickly and correctly respond to events.

Let's play out the scenario you mention and imagine a component on the motherboard detecting a power failure. Without an interrupt the best it can do is write to a register or cache. It must then rely on another piece of hardware or even the operating system to check that value. This basically means periodic polling which is not as efficient. Furthermore, if there is currently a large instruction set running that might be hogging the resources necessary to check the value you have no deterministic way of knowing when that check might occur. It could be near-instant, or it could be a second from now. If it's the latter, your computer loses power and shuts down before it can react.